Hair Clumping Node NOT working when "InterpolateHairCurves" but working when "DuplicateHairCurves"
I have no idea what am I doing wrong, but almost nobody else is having this problem so I am stuck.
I made some hair guides, then added the interpolate node group, after making that work I added a clump modifier.
One would think that it would work right away, well it doesnt, no matter what values I use it just does not work using the existing guides, it clumps everything into a single clump; it does hoever work if you unckeck the "existingGuideMap", but that is not what I want.
Now the kicker: if instead of interpolating I use the "duplicateHairCurves" modifier, the clump node works exactly as expected. Huh? What gives?
I would simply like to use the interpolate, then clump, and the interpolated strands to follow the original guides. What am I missing here?



I finally figured it out, or so I think, at least I made it work.
When doing very small pieces, the numbers are very finicky.
In order the clump modifier to work properly, the interpolate curves modifier HAS to be set properly.
In my case the solution was first to input exactly the number of guides I had made, in this case 7. Then the distance to guides has to be within a reasonable range, in my case very small values, such as 0.011m. I sumbled onto that number starting from zero and watching the interpolated curves spread out, once they are at a reasonable distance, that is my number.
I have no idea if this is what made it work, as I have not managed to replicate the problem, but at least now I have it working.
